# How to keep Servlets to my site only (some sort of authentication)?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I have a website that sends dynamic information to users via servlets. It is stateless and there are no logins. This specific site uses a decent amount of doPost() and doGet() calls from client browser to server.

My question is, if someone reads my source, they can easily just rip out my public facing servlet URL's and have a free API at my web servers expense.

How can I keep this from happening? Is there some kind of authentication package I can use between JavaScript and Java that doesn't add noticeable delays? I would only like users on my webpage to be able to call the public facing servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert but this may help : http://oauth.net/ as I know big web API's like twitter use this.

Comment: thank you @MathanMV, I was looking at oauth but a little nervous about its direction. http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/. Dont know if I should be or not...

Comment: Agree with general sentiment of oauth 2.0.  The simple solution: Use oauth 1.0.  It's stable and well supported.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. REFERRER HTTP header to make sure the client is coming from an
   authorized source
2. require authorized users of your service to provide an API key tied to their website.

Comment: Both of these things can be spoofed if they read his source. But it's what I would probably do. Best effort if you don't want full authentication/authorization.

Comment: The referrer is a little harder because it's transparent -- while it can be spoofed it's not immediately obvious to an attacker that this is the only thing standing between them and free APIs.

Comment: I was hoping for some silver bullet s/w. So how does godaddy or Google for that matter charge an API? Wouldnt everyone just rip out their url instead of paying? What do they do? (thank u btw for your time on this)...

Comment: Google uses API keys.  However, they don't charge for many of their API services.  Their goal isn't to make money on the API, their goal is to make sure people go to Google for information and see ads.  The only other option is to have your users sign in (OAuth can integrate pretty easily)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer -Do you get points in SO when I uptick your comments? Thank you for all of your input! Very helpful!!