# Better Architecture: Oauth with JQuery Ajax or JSP for secuing Servlet?

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, oauth

In a previous post, I had asked the SO community what may be the best way of securing my Servlets so that a user could not simply rip out my url from src and use it as a free api of sorts:

[How to keep Servlets to my site only (some sort of authentication)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865009/how-to-keep-servlets-to-my-site-only-some-sort-of-authentication)

I was directed to look at OAuth 1.0 as it is stable and well supported.

Thinking more on it, what if I used JSP in place of OAuth and jquery ajax?

I could still put all main hard coded files on my Varnish servers and just the ones that need dynamic content would be JSP files that called Servlets for their data, thus not exposing any Servlet address.

**Question(s):** Would this JSP model be acceptable in a production environment? Or is best case scenario to stay with jquery ajax and oauth? Is the difference in speed considerable between these two different scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the previous question.  I don't know that OAuth is strictly the answer (though it could possibly be used).  OAuth is really more geared towards allowing usage of your services via third-party authentication and authorization. In your case, I don't know who that third party would be.

What it does sound like you might want is the concept of an authentication token.  So before a client can call your services, they would need to call one of your services to get an authentication token.  All requests against you servlets would then need to also pass this authentication token and have the token validated as being active prior to you issuing a response.

You mentioned that your servlets are stateless (which is certainly appropriate for many API's), but I am wondering if the client application as a whole has state such that it could acquire such a token via some event (client application login for example) and be able to store the token for sending with each request against the servlets, as well as be able to handle refreshed tokens as tokens near their expiry.

Comment: Thank you for this! No client login (url auction site). But yes, I keep user data on the url bar and parse it in an order to stay stateless. Where each page takes the url bar arg and passes it as a parameter to the servlet. Could I attach an authentication token to this? Or bad idea?

Comment: @Chris This could work, but I would be a little worried about poluting about making session hijacking a little easier.  Have you considered cookies or HTML5 localStorage as alternative options for persisting state?

Comment: Never heard of HTML5 Local Storage... but it looks great! http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html. Where can I learn more about authentication tokening? Thank you @Mike Brant!

Comment: And then my last question to you is back to the original post. Are authentication tokens w/local client storage better (generally speaking) than just using JSP w/Servlet on the back end?

Comment: @Chris I am not all that familiar with Java, so I don;t know if there are any libraries that might be well suited for token based authentication.  Perhaps Google `java token based authentication` to see what you come up with.  I also came across this article on security.stackexchange that I think gives a good idea of how such a token may be formed.  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/token-based-authentication-securing-the-token

Comment: @Chris The good thing about a token-based authentication system is that it can really be client agnostic. Whether you decided to consume the API in a server-to-server context (i.e. with server to server calls when generating your JSP pages) or in a client-server context (AJAX calls directly from client), you could use this form of authentication.  You could even use them intetrchangeably if you wish. Of course if you are just looking for a simple way to secure your API's, in a server-to-server context, you have a number of additional ways to control API access at the network level.

Comment: @ Mike Brant Ive completely ported my application over to HTML5 LocalStorage and it is incredible. I just wanted say thank you again for giving me some of your knowledge. I would have never known this existed... Thank you.

Comment: @Chris Glad to have helped.